# jQuery/Javascript - Connecting two filters - showing only tr's with td's matching an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code currently has 2 separate filters, that filter the table based on their own criteria.

I've created a dumbed down jsfiddle of this specific part of the code.

What I am trying to do is to connect these 2 filters together. So, if, for example, Students is selected, then the button submit filters out only the Students with corresponding to the array numbers, but doesn't touch any other types of drivers.

And likewise, if the table is already filtered, selecting a driver type only works with the rows that are already filtered out.

Here is the code:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    var array = [123, 124, 125, 126];
  var filter = function() {
    var match = false;
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      var currentText = $(this).text();
      var filtered = array.filter(function(value) {
        return value == currentText;
      });
      if (filtered.length > 0) {
        match = true;
      }
    });
    return match;
  };
  $('tr').hide().filter(filter).show();
});

                $('#driverTypes').change(function () {
                    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
                    switch (val) {
                        case 777:
                        $('tr').show();
                        break;
                        case 19:
                        $('tr').hide();
                            $('tr').filter(function() {
                                return $(this).data('filtercriteria') == "Lease Purchase";
                            }).show();
                        break;
                        case 20:
                        $('tr').hide();
                            $('tr').filter(function() {
                                return $(this).data('filtercriteria') == "Company Driver Team";
                            }).show();
                        break;
                        case 21:
                        $('tr').hide();
                            $('tr').filter(function() {
                                return $(this).data('filtercriteria') == "Student";
                            }).show();
                        break;
                        case 22:
                        $('tr').hide();
                            $('tr').filter(function() {
                                return $(this).data('filtercriteria') == "Company Driver";
                            }).show();
                        break;
                    }
                    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m4orLpd3/12/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code that will do what you want. It retains the current filter in a global object. A separate filter is stored per column, and the two are combined when the filter is executed:

```
// List of zip codes of interest
var zipFinal2 = [123, 124, 125, 126];
// Variable to retain currently applied filter:
// An array with a filter per column. 
var columnFilters = [{}, {}, {}, {}]; // add as many as you have columns
var zipColumnNo = 0;
var driverColumnNo = 1;

function applyFilter(filter) {
    $('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).toggle( // show when no TD has mismatching content
            !$(this).find('td').filter(function(idx) {
                // return true when content does not match the filter on this column
                return filter[idx] && Object.keys(filter[idx]).length &&
                                !filter[idx].hasOwnProperty($(this).text());
            }).length
        );
    });
}

$('#zipButton').click(function() {
    // toggle first-column filter:
    var newFilter = {};
    if (!Object.keys(columnFilters[zipColumnNo]).length) {
        // turn zipFinal2[] into object with values as properties for faster lookup
        zipFinal2.forEach(function(zip) {
            newFilter[zip] = 1;
        });
    }
    columnFilters[zipColumnNo] = newFilter;
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
});

$('#driverTypes').change(function () {
    columnFilters[driverColumnNo] =  {}; // no filter
    if (this.selectedIndex) {
         // filter second column on text in selected option
         columnFilters[driverColumnNo][$(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text()] = 1;
    }
    applyFilter(columnFilters);
});

// reset filter on page load:
$(function() {
    $('#driverTypes').val(777);
});
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cy1bk2nf/1/).

As a bonus, this code also treats the "Submit" button (strange name) as a toggle: the filter on that column will be removed when you click it again.

Some browsers retain the last selected value in a drop-down list box when you refresh the page. So I have added at the end the code needed to reset that. Otherwise the situation is inconsistent: all entries of the table become visible, yet a filter is selected in the drop-down.

The code calls the `applyFilter` method whenever one of the two controls is used, and then the `toggle` method is called on all `tr` elements. The argument determines the visibility. Visibility is only set when none of the `td` elements mismatches with the filter. A `td` mismatches if and only when a filter is defined for that column (different from the empty object), and the value in the `td` is not a property of that filter object.

If you expect to run only in `ECMAScript` 6 compatible browsers, you could make the code nicer by using `Set` instead of object properties to store the filter values.

Also, if you expect to use more tables for filtering, you could make this more generic by passing the `table` tag to the applyFilter function, and storing the `columnFilters` array in the `table` tag's data property.

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you. I ran into one problem however: my array is dynamically created through a call to a dynamic XML file, so instead of having a

    var array = [123, 124, 125, 126];

and calling "array" later on, I called a "zipFinal2" variable, which had a few dozen numbers in it, depending on the users input (it is used a zip code filter). In what way can I keep the call to zipFinal2 while maintaining your code?

Comment: I updated the answer. It makes use of the `zipFinal2` variable now, which I have initialised at the top. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, It looks like it should work, but I get this error in the console now

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

And this is the line -             return Object.keys(filter[idx]).length &&

Comment: In the fiddle it works (as you can see via the link I put in my answer), so what did you do differently? Can you share your code in a fiddle maybe? Did you maybe forget to put this line `var columnFilters = [{}, {}];` in the top of your code?

Comment: I can share the code, but it will not work due to multiple ajax calls, so there is no way to debug it in jsfiddle. Yes, that var is present, and I didn't do much differently (except for using a tr variable instead of a "tr", because its dynamically created, therefore, you need to find it based on a pre-existing element of the page).

Comment: Here is the relevant part of the code - http://jsfiddle.net/crmwv5wh/ but I do not have any html, because its dynamically populated via an ajax call to a dynamic XML file.. Do you see any mistakes here, or should I put the entire code into the fiddle? And thank you so much for helping me get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: That looks fine, but another reason could be that your HTML table has more columns. If so, in which columns is the filtering to happen? The first two?

Comment: I have updated my code to take into account that table could have more columns: see extra test on the line where the error occurred . I also added variables you should initialise at the top with the exact zero-based number of the columns used for the zip code and for the driver name. See `zipColumnNo` and `driverColumnNo` throughout the code. I have assumed columns 0 and 1, but you can adapt if you have other columns before or between them.

Comment: Thank you it is great now, with one small issue left, is it possible to remove the toggle effect? The way it is done in the js fiddle is a simple button submit, which might make sense as toggleable, but in my code a person actually writes the zip code and presses search. They are not supposed to "unsearch" it, just write a different postal code, etc. So basically, just filter on click. I guess another button - reset filters would be great, but perhaps I'm asking too much of you, so if you could just make it a permanent filter button, instead of toggle. Thank you!

Comment: Just remove the line `if (!Object.keys(columnFilters[zipColumnNo]).length) {` and closing `}` so the block of code in between executes always.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Another issue that happened is that it doesn't activate on the first click. It might be because of the ajax call not finishing fast enough, but the code keeps going on and activates your function, that has nothing to play with yet, since the ajax results haven't populated the array yet. Is there a way to defer the activation of your function until the ajax call function (in the same snippet I sent you earlier) completes? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just hide or disable the buttons and only show/enable them when you receive the ajax response. But I suggest to close this discussion, because we are diverting from the original question now. You can always ask a new question concerning ajax related issues.

Comment: I'm asking here, because it is related to your solution, it  wouldn't work like that since that button is the same button for filtering. The visitor inputs a zip code, selects radius and presses "Search". The ajax call from the "Search" button returns the array which is later on used in YOUR code, which also tracks clicks on the "Search" button to activate your filter solution.. Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/crmwv5wh/1/ - You can see that its all tied to the zipFinal2. On the first click of the button, the chrome console returns that zipFinal2 is undefined, and works after 2nd click.

Comment: You had the submit button like that already in your fiddle. Honestly, it is bad practice to have the user submit something and then quickly changing the filtering on the table, but this is how you presented it in your question.

Comment: In our fiddles, the array was populated by values already a line above the code, instead of waiting for it to be populated by external code.

// List of zip codes of interest
var zipFinal2 = [123, 124, 125, 126];

The whole concept is to have the zip code list calculation done in the backend, and the whole filtering etc done on the front-end in the browser. I do not see how to go around the "bad practice". It is a job posting list, there are thousands of jobs there.

The wait is only 0.5-1s, but its too slow for your part of code, your function executes before the array is populated.

Comment: Indeed, and you did not mention ajax in your original question either. There was not even form, and the submit button was only named like that, it was not a real submit button. So there was no indication at all about asynchronous communication happening in your original question. I suggest you ask a new question if you still have questions about asynchronous communication and how to deal with that.

Comment: Ok thank you, will do that. The only reason why I didn't mention ajax is because jsfiddle doesn't support ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Modified your filter method. Use $('tr:visible') instead of $('tr').
jQuery hide() equivalent to css( "display", "none" ) which is considered as visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

```
var filter = function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    var result = array.filter(function(id){
        return ((text.indexOf(id) >= 0) ? true : false);
    });
    return !result.length;
};
$('tr:visible').filter(filter).hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m4orLpd3/13/

Comment: Thanks, however it works only with one of the two filters, not vice versa.
Is it possible to make this work with both filters?